# Why is hash recursion faster than lambda recursion?

Tags: ruby, recursion, fibonacci

I found two different solutions on StackOverflow for calculating a Fibonacci number. One uses a `lambda`, like so:

```
f = ->(x){ x < 2 ? x : f[x-1] + f[x-2] }
f[6] # => 8
```

The other uses a `Hash`:

```
f = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = k < 2 ? k : h[k-1] + h[k-2] }
f[6] # => 8
```

The `Hash` version is faster than the `lambda` version.

```
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { f[35] }
  x.report { fibonacci[35] }
end

user       system     total      real
7.332000   0.000000   7.332000  (7.349421)
0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  (0.000000)
```

The `lambda` version can't even calculate `f[100]` in a reasonable amount of time, while the `Hash` version can calculate `fibonacci[1000]` in less than a microsecond. Why is the `Hash` version faster?

Comment: Which Ruby version did you run your benchmark?

Comment: @tlewin My Ruby version is 1.9.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Part of the reason is that the lambda version has to recalculate `f[x-1] + f[x-2]` for every new number, and it has to do that recursively as `x` gets larger.

The hash version remembers those previous calculations and only has to do a hash lookup, which is extremely fast.

The lambda version could be modified to short-circuit the recalculations using memoization or through an external hash that is used as a cache. It'd take a little more code, and a bit more memory, but that would be on par with the hash version.

Comment: Wikipedia has an article on [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) which is useful. Implementing a simple memoizing is easy and takes little code. Implementing one that is comprehensive and doesn't grow to consume all available space in a long-running application is another problem. For a Fibonacci generator I think allowing it to keep precomputed values within a reasonable range makes sense, but keeping arbitrarily large ranges could open you up to a DOS attack if someone told it to generate 100,000 which fills your RAM. It's a balance between speed and common sense.

Answer (score 2):

The Hash version keep the calculated data on memory and the lambda version don't.

If you run hash_fibonnacci[10] and print the object: "p hash_fibonnacci" you will see all the intermediate results calculated.

Every lambda call will redo all calculation, recursively, until the number 2. When you call lambda_fibonnacci[10], it calculated it, approximately, 170 times and the Hash implemetation just 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wrong way to do recursion for Fibonacci, you are creating a huge tree of calls before you get to edge conditions. Can be easily avoided by using tail recursion (not optimized in Ruby though):

```
f = 
  lambda do |x| 
    f0 = 
      lambda do |a, b, y| 
        y > 0 ? f0[b, a + b, y - 1] : a
      end
    f0[0, 1, x]
  end
p (0..100).map(&f)
```